# Will the following construction leads to an counterexample of strong mapping conjecture on realizable oriented matroids?

Tags: co.combinatorics, oriented-matroids

The strong map conjecture asserts that any strong map $\mathcal{M}_1\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_2$ admit a factorization into an extension followed by a contraction. For which the counterexample has been constructed and in that counter example $\mathcal{M}_1$ is non-realizable. In the book "Oriented Matroids" it has been noted that whether an counterexample with $\mathcal{M}_1$ realizable is still an open question. I don't know too much with this field and with the literatures I've read this problem seems still open.

I've think of the following construction and it is likely to leads to an counterexample, I'm not very sure such construction has been considered by others. Think of $\mathcal{M}_1$  being some cyclic oriented matroid of rank $5$, which can be realized by trigonometric moment curve $(\sin t,\cos t,\sin 2t,\cos 2t)$. And $\mathcal{M}_2$ be oriented matroid induced by the points on hypotrochoid as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Topes of $\mathcal{M}_1$ is all sign vectors of the form $(+\dots+-\dots-+\dots+-\dots-+\dots+)$ or $(+\dots+-\dots-+\dots+)$, and any line would intersect with the hypotrochoid at most $4$ times, this proves $\mathcal{M}_1\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_2$ is a strong map. And if it can be factored as an extension followed by a contraction, the extension can not be realizable in the sense that the coordinates of ground set of $\mathcal{M}_1$ still be in the form of $(\sin t,\cos t,\sin 2t,\cos 2t)$. Or the contraction can be realized as a rational mapping and the result planar curve is of finite degree thus cannot have unbounded number of inflection points, this leads to a contradiction. Now the problem is, can we show that, this kind of geometric argument can be extended into arbitrary extension?